# gitlab local instance can't clone from itself on localhost

Tags: git, gitlab

I started a gitlab instance on localhost, and when I

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname localhost \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 23:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  --shm-size 256m \
  gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

Then I started the runner as a docker in docker service:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

But then the CI job is unable to clone itself:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://localhost/myusername/myproject.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am relatively sure that the issue here is that `localhost` inside the container is different from `localhost` in the host environment. Try to substitute with a proper fqdn.